# How to insert pair<string, CUSTOM_CLASS> into multimap C++

Tags: c++, stl, insert, containers, multimap

How can I insert `pair<string, CUSTOM_CLASS>` into multimap? pair() function is answering "no instance of constructor..."

What am I doing wrong?

MY code:

```
using namespace std;

class CUSTOM_CLASS{
    public:
        string state;
        multimap<string, CUSTOM_CLASS> relation;
        bool isStart = false;
        bool isEnd = false;
}

CUSTOM_CLASS findNext(string s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < automat.size(); i++) {
        if (automat.at(i).stav == s) {
            return automat.at(i);
        }
    }
}

void assignRelation(string f, string i, string w) {

    multimap<string, CUSTOM_CLASS> tmp;
    CUSTOM_CLASS where;

    for (int i = 0; i < automat.size(); i++) {
        if (automat.at(i).stav == f) {
            where = findNext(w);

            tmp.insert(pair<string, CUSTOM_CLASS>(i, where));



        }
    }
}
```

And this gives me error.

Comment: What is the error message? Does `CUSTOM_CLASS` have a copy constructor?

Comment: What is `automat`?

Comment: Hint: You have a `string` named `i` and an `int` named `i`. What do you think is going to happen?